# Selected value of dropdown inside foreach - Razor

Tags: c#, razor, selectedvalue

I pass a list of objects using viewbag in the controller's action to my view:

```
 ViewBag.subGroupNameList = DbContext.SubGroups.ToList();
```

and render the dropdowns like that inside a foreach in the cshtml view:

```
   @Html.DropDownList("subGroupNameList", new SelectList(ViewBag.subGroupNameList, "id", "subGroupName", item.SubGroupId))
```

where the item.SubGroupId is the id of the selected value of dropdown in that specific row.
Problem is that the selected value does not get selected after loading.

Any idea why this happens? 
Thank you

Comment: Wow, `ViewBag` + weakly typed `Html.DropDownList` helper. It's been a while since I have seen so much suffering. I wonder why's there so much misery in this world.

Comment: tell me about that. an old project :)

Comment: I would have understand that if you say *an old project* to a classic ASP website or WebForms, but this even looks like if it is an ASP.NET MVC application. I didn't know those were already considered as old projects.

Comment: it is :) any solution in mind?

Comment: No, really, what kind of solution do you want to give to a dying being other than starting all over from scratch.

Comment: try  @Html.DropDownList("subGroupNameList", new SelectList(ViewBag.subGroupNameList, "id", "subGroupName", item)) (remove the SubGroupId)

Comment: @LazyCoder didn't help

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x =>item.SubGroupId, new SelectList(ViewBag.subGroupNameList, "id", "subGroupName", item.SubGroupId))
```